# Can't make a API request in DialogFlow and actions-on-google. No response has been set

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I'm trying to make a API request using actions-on-google and dialogflow, but after the call has been resolved, the conv.ask does not count as a final response i guess.

My code:

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {dialogflow,Permission} = require('actions-on-google');
const request = require('request');
const rp = require('request-promise-native');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
 
const app = dialogflow();

const API_URL = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/1/";

app.intent('CriarLista - produtos - yes', (conv) => {
    conv.data.requestedPermission = 'DEVICE_PRECISE_LOCATION';
    return conv.ask(new Permission({
        context: 'Para te localizar',
        permissions: conv.data.requestedPermission,
    }));
});
app.intent('CriarLista - location_permission', (conv, params, permissionGranted) => {
    if (permissionGranted) {
        const {requestedPermission} = conv.data;
        if (requestedPermission === 'DEVICE_PRECISE_LOCATION') {
        
            const {coordinates} = conv.device.location;
            
            if (coordinates) {
                let lat = coordinates.latitude;
                let long = coordinates.longitude;

                fetch(API_URL).then(function(res) {
                    let data = res.json();
                }).then(function(data) {
                    conv.ask('Test');
                }).catch(function(err) {
                    console.log(err);
                });
                
            } else {
                return conv.close('Sorry, I could not figure out where you are.');
            }
        }
    } else {
        return conv.close('Sorry, permission denied.');
    }
});
 
exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

**Errors:**
actions-on-google response:

```
{
  "responseMetadata": {
    "status": {
      "code": 10,
      "message": "Failed to parse Dialogflow response into AppResponse because of empty speech response",
      "details": [
        {
          "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.protobuf.Value",
          "value": "{\"id\":\"74f26d40-869c-4ccb-9d75-1473f42e9aee\",\"timestamp\":\"2018-10-06T15:33:01.004Z\",\"lang\":\"pt-br\",\"result\":{},\"status\":{\"code\":206,\"errorType\":\"partial_content\",\"errorDetails\":\"Webhook call failed. Error: 500 Internal Server Error\"},\"sessionId\":\"ABwppHEUqmeurK1aqRe3QRDCo2BrPyZOu4cI447He8ZgA882v72AICpeqPCyzHEA6QCKTeo4cn4CzIZ9ACozv15L\"}"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Firebase console:

```
FetchError: request to https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/1/ failed, reason: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN pokeapi.co:443

Error: No response has been set. Is this being used in an async call that was not returned as a promise to the intent handler?
```

Says that i need to return a promise, i guess a "resolve" method, but i tried even making my promise and it does not work, the "then" from the fetch method is already a resolve method returned from a promise. I tried node-fetch, request, request-promise-native..

Running only the conv.ask outside the fetch block works normally after deploying to firebase.

There is a right way of doing external requests in DialogFlow/actions-on-google environment?

Comment: Are you using Blaze plan on Firebase? You need to have paid plan to make the external requests, like API call.

Comment: @Denis No, i got it to make the request, but i realize that i need a Blaze plan at least to return a response. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `return` the promise object so the webhook knows to wait until the promise is completed.

Since `fetch()` already returns a Promise (as do all the `.then()` calls after it, since that's how one typically uses a Promise), you just need to return that promise. So you can change the line to

```
            return fetch(API_URL).then(function(res) {
                let data = res.json();
            }).then(function(data) {
                conv.ask('Test');
            }).catch(function(err) {
                console.log(err);
            });
```

Comment: i tried using return Promise.resolve() already, how can i do it in fetch?

Comment: Just return the Promise that `fetch()` already returns. I've added some sample code.